# What is the verbose option in mkdir?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, mkdir

I was working my way through a primer on *Shell (Bash) Scripting* and noticed the manpage of `mkdir` describes a verbose option which displays a message when a directory is created:

> ```
> -v, --verbose
>        print a message for each created directory
> ```

It seems `mkdir -v` has a pre-defined message it prints. Is there a way to print a custom message? Is there a way to permanently set a custom message instead of the default message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the source code for `mkdir.c`](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.23.orig.tar.gz), this is the section that deals with the `-v` option:

```
    case 'v': /* --verbose  */
      options.created_directory_format = _("created directory %s");
      break;
```

As you can see, the string that is used is hard-coded into the source.  To permanently change the message to a custom message, one can modify this section of the source code and recompile `mkdir`.

Comment: The `_(...)` means it's *not* strictly hard-coded.  Rather, a `gettext` lookup on the hard-coded source string is performed, and the result of that lookup is what is actually printed.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script like this:

```
#/bin/bash

/bin/mkdir "$@" |sed -e"s/mkdir: created directory /$USER created folder /"
```

Then run that script rather than mkdir.

Modify that script for each message you want to change by adding an additional -e"s/x/y" to the sed.

If you insist on it being named mkdir, then you can put it in your search path before mkdir.

I would not recommend naming it mkdir.  You will only cause yourself grief for other scripts that call mkdir

Comment: The message is printed to standard error, so your `sed` is not seeing the output from `mkdir`.

Comment: @tripleee : I tested on my mac and mkdir outputs the message to stdout.  I did not test on Linux.  OP asked for Linux, so my bad.

Comment: Also, you should always double-quote `"$@"`.

Comment: @tripleee: I just tested on CentOS 6.3.  The verbose message comes out of stdout.  What Linux are you testing on?

Comment: Debian 6.0.10, Coreutils 8.5.

Comment: @tripleee: Could you test my script on Debian?  Testing your script is not conclusive on whether the verbose message is coming out of stderr.    Thanks for the tip on quoting $@.  It is interesting bash essentially quotes  each element in the array.  My intuition was that the quote would have put all elements in one string.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct, I must have mistyped something the first time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are satisfied with a wrapper, try something like

```
mkdir -v "$@" | sed 's/mkdir: created directory /jar-jar: yea, weesa gotta /'
```

More fundamentally, the message string in `mkdir` is usually more or less hard-coded.  However, if there is localization support, you could actually override the message catalog with your own.

For example, if your `mkdir` was built with `gettext`, you could create a new English `.po` file, replace the directory creation message, build a new locale, and run with that.  See also http://translationproject.org/domain/coreutils.html

Depending on what you want, this is somewhere between severe overkill and insane.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try and run it with this flag?

```
lgml-alfasi2:dotfiles alfasi$ mkdir -v tp
mkdir: created directory 'tp'  <-- see why it is called 'verbose' ?
lgml-alfasi2:dotfiles alfasi$
```

from the man:

```
-v      Be verbose when creating directories, listing them as they are created.
```

So to your other question: no - you cannot "custom" a pre-defined message

That said, this is an open source project, so if you feel like it - you can create your own fork, submit PR etc: http://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-212/mkdir/mkdir.c

Comment: The link is to OSX sources (i.e. basically BSD), not Linux (i.e. GNU `coreutils`).

Comment: @tripleee you're right, google shows multiple versions of mkdir, such http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/cmds/mkdir.c.html

Comment: The authoritative source is http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mkdir.c